# Retrieve active directory attributes with JavaScript and c# controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a SamAccountName that is typed in by the user and upon clicking enter in a contenteditable element, send that username to a C# MVC Controller which in turn queries Active Directory and return `firstname` and an `email`.

I'm currently getting `[object object]` and `undefined` back from the controller.

This is currently what I have and now I am seeking advice.

**Javascript**

```
     $.ajax({
         url: "@Url.Action("GetUserDetails")",
         data: { 'PIC': userPIC },
         type: 'GET',
         success: function (userData) {
            alert(userData.Name);
            alert(userData.Email);
         },
         error: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
         }
     });
```

*(Using alerts above just to see if I can get the data back.)*

**Controller**

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }


    public ActionResult GetUserDetails(string PIC)
    {

        string ldapAddress = "ldapaddress";
        string name = "NA";
        string email = "NA";

        try
        {
            using (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry de = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(ldapAddress, "username", "pass"))
            {
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
                ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=p722))";
                ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

                if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
                {

                    name = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();

                    email = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception b)
        {


        }

        UserModel userData = new UserModel();
        userData.Name = name;
        userData.Email = email;

        return Json(userData);
    }
```

**Solved!**

```
  var js = new JsonSerializerSettings();

        return Json(userData, js);
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? Was the c# controller returning your expected values?

Comment: did u successfully get you desired data in `name` and `email` variable?

Comment: try to set debugger in Ajax success what do you get in  `userData`

Comment: Jsonrequsestbehavior.AllowGet

Comment: Solved. Edited original post with updates. Thanks Nikhil for the push in the right direction.